# Operator-overloading surprisingly works but I can't figure out, why

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-overloading

In my programming with C++ lessons I have to solve a practical problem.
My program works, but I don't understand why.

The solution to the task is to execute the main function correctly

```cpp
int main()
{ 
    STRING M1 = "Max";
    STRING M2("Moritz");
    STRING M3;
    M3 = M1 + " und " + M2;
    std::cout << "Wilhelm Busch:\n" << M3 << "\n";
    M1 = "______________";
    M1[0] = '+';
    M1[M1.GetLength() - 1] = M1[0];
    std::cout << M1 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and produce the following console output:

```
Wilhelm Busch:
Max und Moritz
+------------+
```

We created a Class `STRING`, which got several constructors:

```cpp
class STRING
{
    char *pBuf;
    int Len;
public:
    STRING() : pBuf(nullptr), Len(0){};

    STRING(const char *pStr) : Len(strlen(pStr))
    {
        pBuf = new char[Len + 1];
        strcpy(pBuf, pStr);
    };
    STRING(const STRING &other) : Len(other.Len)
    {
        pBuf = new char[Len + 1];
        strcpy(pBuf, other.pBuf);
    };
    STRING(char C) : Len(6) //for testing purposes
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pBuf[i] = C;
        }
        pBuf[5] = '\0';
    };
...
}
```

We wrote some operator overloads like these:

```cpp
STRING &operator=(const STRING &other)
{
    if (&other == this)
        return *this;
    delete[] pBuf;
    this->Len = other.Len;
    pBuf = new char[Len + 1];
    strcpy(pBuf, other.pBuf);
    return *this;
};
STRING operator+(const STRING &other)
{
    char *temp = new char[other.Len + this->Len + 1];
    strcpy(temp, this->pBuf);
    strcat(temp, other.pBuf);
    STRING newString(temp);
    delete[] temp;
    return newString;
};
```

Now in the main function I don't understand the line

```cpp
M3 = M1 + " und " + M2;
```

It surprisingly does work correctly but my operator (`STRING operator+(const STRING &other)`) does not support values from the datatype `char*` which `" und "` is, but only from the object `STRING`.
There is no other operator `operator+` in my code.

When I try to rewrite the same line like this:

```cpp
M3 = M1 + 'D' + M2;
```

the program does compile but does not give any output and terminates after several seconds.
I would expect the result `MaxDDDDDMoritz` if the compiler automatically creates a temporary instance of the class `STRING` with the corresponding constructor.
(I added a constructor `STRING(char C)` for the purpose of testing this line.)

Comment: Side note: classes need a `;` at the end. Methods and functions do not. Your code seems to have this backward.

Comment: *It surprisingly does work correctly but my operator does not support values from the datatype `char*`*. You have a converting constructor `STRING(const char *pStr)` that makes `STRING` from `const char*` for you. Mark it `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
But why would `M3 = 1 + 'D' + M2;` not work, since i got a constructor `STRING(char C)`, so it could also convert automatically but it does not.
so my question is:
When does automatic conversions happen and when not?

Comment: Fun fact: `" und "` isn't a `char *`. What you have there is a `const char [6]` which will decay to a `const char *`. It's one of those neat little things that won't really matter until it suddenly matters a lot. For example, if you change `STRING(const char *pStr)` to `STRING(char *pStr)` suddenly you see some interesting problems and a hint as to what had you puzzled: https://godbolt.org/z/EK8K1voE7

Comment: Please focus your question and code on the actual question. There's a lot of background information that is not necessary. (At best, put it at the end if you think the context might be useful, but it should not be the start of the question.) See [ask] for tips on introducing your question **before** posting any code.

Comment: Side note: when asking a question it is in your best interest to provide example code that demonstrates the misbehaviour--and nothing else--in as simple a package as possible. Readers should be able to take your example, paste it into their tools, compile it, and see the same behaviour you do (or at the very least something they can identify the result of Undefined Behaviour) without making any changes to the code. The more you make people work, the less useful it will be to future askers. Worse, every change we have to make is a an opportunity to fix the mistake or add a new one.

Comment: @Ummel FYI:  If you have a user-defined destructor for `STRING` then `operator=` can be as simple as -- `STRING &operator=(STRING other) { std::swap(other.pBuf, pBuf); std::swap(other.Len, Len); return *this; }` -- See [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I will wrap up future questions and provide less information which arent absolutely necessary.
I will look into copy and swap!

Comment: @Ummel *"I will wrap up future questions"* -- I think you should not wait and instead [edit] **this** question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to an operator overload works in exactly the same way as calls to other functions.

In particular your

```
STRING operator+(const STRING &other);
```

overload can be called with a `STRING` argument. However, a `const` lvalue reference (i.e. `const&`) can bind to not only lvalue expressions, but also to rvalue expressions. That means it can also bind to a temporary object of type `STRING`.

Generally in C++ when calling a function implicit conversions are always considered on the function argument to convert it to the target type. That's why e.g. `void g(long);` can also be called as `g(1)`, although `1` has type `int`, not `long`. The `int` object in the function parameter is initialized by implicitly converting the `long` value `1` to `int`, which in this case results in the same value `1` for the `int` object.

Implicit conversions don't happen only between fundamental types, but also from and to user-defined types like your `STRING`.

In particular, for these so-called *user-defined conversion sequences*, among others, any constructor of the target class that takes a single argument and is not marked with the keyword `explicit` can be considered for the conversion.

You have a constructor `STRING(const char *);` that matches this. It can be used to convert a `const char*` to a `STRING`. This new `STRING` object is then a temporary object living until the end of the (full-)expression in which it was created, i.e. the end of `M3 = M1 + " und " + M2`, and the reference parameter of your `operator+` will bind to this temporary `STRING` object, which has the correct type for the reference.

Therefore the overload is viable and since there is no other viable overload, the compiler will use it like that.

The same happens with `'D'` since you have a `STRING(char C);` constructor. You see that it still compiles. It then fails at runtime only because you forgot to initialize `pBuf` in that constructor, i.e. the line `pBuf = new char[Len + 1];` is missing. Therefore the constructor has undefined behavior for reading the pointer's value uninitialized.